# Optimally send base64-encoded JSON in nodejs request

Tags: json, node.js, string, base64

I have some base64 encoded JSON, for example: `eyJiYXIiOiJibGFuIn0=` (this is just `{"bar": "blan"}`.

I'm using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to make an http request, although I'm willing to use another library or `http` if need be. I want to be able to transmit the data as a JSON string with as few steps / as efficiently as possible.  Currently I do:

```
axios({
    url,
    method: "POST",
    data: new Buffer(data, "base64").toString(),
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
})
```

However, this reads the entire string into memory from the buffer, so I'm wondering if there is a better way. If I don't use `toString` it doesn't work, and the JSON parser on the server responds with: `Unexpected token '`.

Is there a better way to transmit data from a base64-encoded string?